# HmacSHA1 different result in Node crypto and CryptoJS

Tags: node.js, nativescript, cryptojs

I am implementing two factor authentication with Google Authenticator in a NativeScript app starting from [this implementation](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-implement-google-authenticator-two-factor-auth-in-javascript-091wy3vh3). Since Node's crypto module doesn't run inside NativeScript, I am trying to make it work with CryptoJS.

This is the working Node code. The function returns a buffer with the correct value.

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

function generateHOTP(secret, counter) {
    const buffer = Buffer.alloc(8);
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
       buffer[7 - i] = counter & 0xff;
       counter = counter >> 8;
    }

    const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', secret);
    hmac.update(buffer);
    return hmac.digest();
}
```

This is the CryptoJS equivalent. The value returned is different than the previous function, and sometimes it returns the same value for many iterations regardless of the input.

```js
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

function generateHOTP(secret, counter) {
    const buffer = Buffer.alloc(8);
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
       buffer[7 - i] = counter & 0xff;
       counter = counter >> 8;
    }

    let result = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(buffer.toString(), secret); // buffer.toString() is the problem
    return Buffer.from(result.toString(), "hex");
}
```

If in the first function I change `hmac.update(buffer)` to `hmac.update(buffer.toString())`, it returns the same wrong value as the second one, so the issue lies in this string conversion. `buffer` is an UInt8Array.

How can I fix the first parameter of `CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(message, key)` to return the same value as the first function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are giving a Buffer to the crypto module, while you are giving a string to CryptoJS. Probably they do not handle the strings the same as Buffers. CryptoJS does not support a Buffer as input, only string and WordArray, so the trick is to convert your Buffer into a WordArray:

Change the following line:

```js
let result = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(buffer.toString(), secret);
```

to:

```js
let result = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(buffer), secret);
```

If you want the code to be more in line with the crypto version (CryptoJS has a similar interface):

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

function generateHOTP(secret, counter) {
    const buffer = Buffer.alloc(8);
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        buffer[7 - i] = counter & 0xff;
        counter = counter >> 8;
    }

    const hmac = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(CryptoJS.algo.SHA1, secret);
    hmac.update(CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(buffer))
    return Buffer.from(hmac.finalize().toString(), 'hex');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the last code block got it working! I read about WordArray in the docs but didn't figure how to use it.